# No resources found when installing kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I am install kubernetes dashboard using this command:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ~]# kubectl create -f kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created
```

this is my kubernetes yaml config:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-dashboard
        image: registry.cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/minminmsn/kubernetes-dashboard:v1.10.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
        args:
          - --auto-generate-certificates
          # Uncomment the following line to manually specify Kubernetes API server Host
          # If not specified, Dashboard will attempt to auto discover the API server and connect
          # to it. Uncomment only if the default does not work.
          # - --apiserver-host=http://my-address:port
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
          mountPath: /certs
          # Create on-disk volume to store exec logs
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-volume
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTPS
            path: /
            port: 8443
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
        secret:
          secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
      - name: tmp-volume
        emptyDir: {}
      serviceAccountName: kubernetes-dashboard
      # Comment the following tolerations if Dashboard must not be deployed on master
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule

---
# ------------------- Dashboard Service ------------------- #

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

get the result:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ~]# kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.43.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   102d
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    10.254.180.117   <none>        443:31720/TCP   58s
metrics-server         ClusterIP   10.43.96.112     <none>        443/TCP         102d

[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ~]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
No resources found.
```

but when I check the port 31720:

```
lsof -i:31720
```

the output is empty.Is the service deploy success? How to check the deploy log? Why the port not binding success?

Comment: Dolphin, the output of your command   
kubectl get svc -n kube-system must show you a lot of pods running on your Master Node.

Comment: NodePort it's virtual not an actual IP. It is an entry in Iptables or VPS depending how you installed kubernetes. First try to findout why you can't list your pods in namespace kube-system

Comment: kube-system doesn't have to show lots of pods if you install components as systemd services.

Comment: What's the output of the command ```kubectl get deployment -n kube-system```? If you can see the dashboard deployment, try to describe it to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

it is under its own namespace - "kubernetes-dashboard". So, just use kubectl get all -n kubernetes-dashboard to see everything

Comment: mybe it is a network issue, the kubernetes image could not access from china. @Paul

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create kubernetes dashboard by typing a command `minikube dashboard` then kubernetes-dashboard will created automatically.
Check in `kubectl get ns` or `kubectl get namespace`
so, you just use `kubectl get all -n kubernetes-dashboard`